# Accessing vue-router from actions.ts

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How do we get access to the Vue router instance from within our actions.ts file?  `this.$router` and `this.$route` aren't available in the following context:

boot.ts:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';
import store from './services/store'
import * as log from 'loglevel'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

log.setLevel("trace");

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: router,
    store: store,
    render: h => h(require('./layouts/app.vue.html'))
});
```

actions.ts:

```js
import { http, httpClass } from './http';
import { DomainAppModel } from '../models/domainApps';
import Vue from 'vue';

var actions = {
    LOGOUT: function ({ commit }, params) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            http.logout().then(result => {
                commit('CLEAR_STATE');                
                // this.$router and this.$route not available
                this.$router.push({
                    path:"login", 
                    query: {
                        sessionTimedout: true,
                        redirect: this.$route.fullPath
                    }
                });
            });
        });      
    }
}

export default actions
```

Comment: Resolve the `Promise` in the `.then` handler via `resolve()` and then wherever you're dispatching the action: `this.$store.dispatch('LOGOUT', params).then(() => this.$router.push({...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$router:**

In order to access `$router` in the store actions you can do it like this:

move your router declaration to a separate file named `router.ts`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: "active"
});
export default router;
```

Import your `router` in `actions.ts` and use it instead of `this.$router` like this:

```
import router from './router';

// then use the router like this
router.push({path: 'login'})
```

**$route.fullPath**

Concerning `$route.fullPath`, you can pass it as a property of the payload when the action is dispatched

```
this.$store.dispatch('LOGOUT', {redirectPath: this.$route.fullPath})
```

then use it like this in the `LOGOUT` action

```
router.push({path:"login", query: {
  sessionTimedout: true,
  redirect: params.redirectPath
}});
```